# Scala: import class from different file

Tags: scala, function, import

In Scala, I would like to separate my class from the main function and put it in a separate file.

My working example is shown below. When I put the content of point.scala into xtest.scala. I can load the file `:load xtest.scala` and execute the code through `Demo.main(Array("h"))`. That's working just fine.

However, once I separate the the class from the main function. I follow the procedure of compiling it using Maven:

1. mvn compile
2. mvn package

This gives me the jar-file Test/target/Test-0.0.1.jar in which I have Point.class. How do I import this jar file in my main function?
`import Test.target.Point` does not seem to work.

point.scala:

```
class Point(val xc: String) {
   var x: String = xc;

   def plot(dx: String): String = {
      val output: String = x + " " + dx;
      return output;
   }
}
```

xtest.scala:

```
import Test.target.Test.Point

object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val pt = new Point("Hello,");

      var greeting: String = pt.plot("Jack");
      println(greeting);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do I actually have to take the route via jar-compilation or can I import point.scala directly?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added `package Test.target.Test`..

point.scala

```
package Test.target.Test

class Point(val xc: String) {
   var x: String = xc;

   def plot(dx: String): String = {
      val output: String = x + " " + dx;
      return output;
   }
}
```

xtest.scala

```
import Test.target.Test.Point

object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val pt = new Point("Hello,");

      var greeting: String = pt.plot("Jack");
      println(greeting);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.